# Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to type 'JsonData'

Tags: c#, json, exception

i have defined this class for decoding json response

```
      private class JsonData
      {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api-author")]
        public string apiauthor { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api-usage")]
        public string apiusage { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]

        public string status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "language")]
        public string language { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sentiment-text")]
        public string sentimenttext { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sentiment-score")]
        public string sentimentscore { get; set; }
    }
```

and i am trying to call an api

```
string url = "https://loudelement-free-natural-language-processing-service.p.mashape.com/nlp-text/?text=";

            var response = Unirest.get(url)
           .header("X-Mashape-Key", "AlZVYH30C9mshLPNM7KiE48aFfTHp1h3A31jsnmVPccxBzW5uB")
           .header("Accept", "application/json")
           .asJson<JsonData>()
           .Body
           ;

            var status = response.sentimenttext;
```

where i am getting this exception

> An exception of type System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   unirest-net.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to type
>   'JsonData'.

Comment: asjson response that is being received by calling the mashape api..

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. What does the code in `asJson` look like? What does it do? What does it return?

Comment: asjson is returning 

"api-author": "Taewook Kang (taewook.kang@gmail.com)",
  "api-usage": "completely free as long as you give me credit somewhere on your website.",
  "status": "OK",
  "language": "english",
  "sentiment-text": "negative",
  "sentiment-score": "-0.171441"

Comment: Can you post the code of `asJson` ?

Comment: I looked over the code for Unirest once I discovered you were using a 3rd party library and I would stay clear of this library as it will create potential deadlocks, seeing as it using blocking async code. I did not see why it threw that particular exception but if none of your code tries to case a stream to a JsonData, then it is safe to say there's some failed assumptions in that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about writing your own methods instead of using that library

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Mashape-Key", "AlZVYH30C9mshLPNM7KiE48aFfTHp1h3A31jsnmVPccxBzW5uB");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

Now you can call it as

```
string url =  "https://loudelement-free-natural-language-processing-service.p.mashape.com/nlp-text/?text=apple";
var jsonData = await Get<JsonData>(url);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: when i add this piece of code i get error Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Add `async` keyword to your method.. See for example the ` Get<T>` method.

Comment: i am trying to call this async method in sync method and getting the error Error "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'."

Comment: "How about writing your own methods instead of using that library". How is this possibly the solution? I hope I don't need to explain why you would want to use a library instead of writing your own code...